EIP-712 ethersjs
I want to replicate the following with lower level calls to have partial steps
const signature = await user._signTypedData(
    domain,
    types,
    values
  );

When I test this signature submitting to my smart contract it works perfectly fine.
I want to get the order digest myself before it's signed.
Why does this not work?
  const digest = ethers.utils.keccak256(
    ethers.utils.hexConcat([
      "0x1901",
      ethers.utils._TypedDataEncoder.hashDomain(domain),
      ethers.utils._TypedDataEncoder.from(types).hash(values),
    ])
  );

  const signatureFromDigest = await user.signMessage(digest);
  
  const recoveredAddressWithDigest = ethers.utils.recoverAddress(
    digest,
    signatureFromDigest
  );

  // recoveredAddressWithDigest !== user.address

